# Сохранить состояние Activity перед закрытием приложения

Tags: java, android, sqlite, activity, checkbox

Проблема в том что у меня есть несколько активити и в них находиться под 250 объектов(CheckBox, EditText), мне нужно сохранить состояние их всех перед закрытием и при повторном входе в программу все поля были в том же состоянии. Сейчас мне удалось этого достичь через  SQLite но там такой го*нокод. Есть ли лучше путь для сохранения и возобновления данных?

Comment: А вы пробовали сохранять через `SharedPreferences` ?

Comment: пробовал, все ровно не удобно сохранять 250 объектов

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно сохранять список однотипных элементов, например `CheckBox`, то правильнее сохранять в базе данных, разделяя данные по таблицам. Если же нужно сохранить состояние одного элемента, то лучше воспозоваться классом [SharedPreference](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html)

Comment: есть какой то более елегантний способ обратно эти данные считать и вставить в нужные поля? поскольку у меня CheckBox штук так 50 в проекте и писать вручную код что б вставлять для каждого как то по тупому мне кажется. Не хочется писать вот так для каждого поля
 if ((DATA.name()).equals(cursor.getString(name))) {
                    entry_data.setText(cursor.getString(value));
                }

Comment: Если их у вас 50, скорее всего у вас используется список, в этом случае проблем с установкой значений быть не должно. Если же нет, то тогда это скорее всего проблема дизайна или решения.

Comment: я могу все эти обьекты сделать списком, но как сделать соответсвие, как понять в какой обьект списка какую информацию вставлять. Будет к примеру список 3 объектов  
1. EditText (email)
2. EditText (password)
3) EditText (login)
как подвязать каждому полю своё значение, если есть идеии можете озвуить.
У меня были планы использовать для этого orm но также появились сложнсти

Comment: Эти поля не однотипные, их нужно сохранять в SharedPreference. Если у вас все 250 объектов не однотипные, то тогда их все сохраняйте в нем. Более удобных вариантов нет.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала стоит подумать, что такое состояние активити, вернее что на него влияет. Скорее всего вы в активити сетите какие-то данные и на их основе изменяются виджеты. Необходимо понимать, что данные относятся к слою Model. т.е. представляют собой бизнес логику, которая не зависит от визуального представления (слой View). Для таких данных пишут модельные классы. и хранят их объекты в БД.

И опишите пожалуйста ваше приложение. как это 250 объектов? Что это за объекты такие? Вы для каждого чекбокса пишете в БД его состояние? Это не верно. 
Верно - у вас есть, к примеру, объект Кот у него поля возраст / имя / обрезан или нет. И эти поля отображает ваш UI для возраста и имени TextView для 3 параметра CheckBox или Switch. В общем ваш UI должен заниматься тем, что отображает модели, а не наоборот - вы в модель пишете состояние UI, так не правильно. Вы через UI можете поменять объект Кот. и потом он запишется в БД

Comment: вы предлагаете использовать hibernate, я так понимаю?

Comment: hibernate это из мира java enterprise. В мобильной разработке другие ОРМ. я советую Room. Но суть одна - да, вам нужна база данных. какую ОРМ вы выберите - решать вам. опишите поподробнее ваше приложение. что за 250 объектов. может мы сможем дать более четкий совет